# Xamarin Forms Pick all type of files

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need any tool to pick files from phone in PCL Project 
Currently I using the following tool 
[MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)
put what i want is to pick all type of file

is there any plugin to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this file picker:
https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows

All you have to do is to install the nuget (you can find it in the link provided) and after that you can put this simple line of code in an async method:

```
FileData file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
```